# C# : bool array is not updating during execution

Tags: c#, for-loop, boolean

i have this sample code which basically reads some string data from csv file and updates in textboxes and some variables.

The csv file is of the format `10,0,20,0,0,30,0..etc` with 20 values. The idea is, if any of the value in csv file is `0`, the `isCashAvailable` variable should be set to `false` and vice versa. Below is my code.

```
int[] cash = new int[20];
bool[] isCashAvailable = new bool[20];

public void UpdateCash()
{
        var cashCSV = File.ReadAllText("cash.csv");
        List<string> cashVal = cashCSV.Split(',').ToList();
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
           {
            var control = this.Controls.Find("textBox" + i.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
            if (cashVal[i - 1] != "0")
              {
                 isCashAvailable[i - 1] = true;
                 control.Text = cashVal[i - 1];
                 cash[i - 1] = int.Parse(cashVal[i - 1]);
              }
                            
            else
              {
                 isCashAvailable[i - 1] = false;
                 control.Text = cashVal[i - 1];
                 cash[i - 1] = int.Parse(cashVal[i - 1]);
                 
              }
           }
}
```

Now the issue is, when I try to update the value of the `isCashAvailable` and `cash` in runtime, its not updating. Whereas if am debugging it by stepping over each iteration, its updating. Can't seem to find why this is happening.

Comment: How can you tell what happens in runtime? The array is locally declared and thus not used outside the current block.

Comment: the array is declared globally. For understanding, i included it like this. my mistake. Also i have remaining code where i am getting desired output if i debug the iteration one at a time.

Comment: Please share the exact context, code and technology used. No other way for us to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int[] cash = new int[20];
bool[] isCashAvailable = new bool[20];

var cashCSV = File.ReadAllText("cash.csv");
List<string> cashVal = cashCSV.Split(',').ToList();

// changing this allows you to use i+1 just once, instead of doing i-1 over and over
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   {
    // this way it will throw an error if TextBox is not found instead of
    // not throwing it here and then throwing NullReference later
    var control = this.Controls.Find("textBox" + (i+1).ToString(), true).First() as TextBox;
    
    //if-else is not needed here
    //TryParse to make sure it always works
    int.TryParse(cashVal[i], out cash[i]);
    isCashAvailable[i] = (cash[i] > 0);
    control.Text = cashVal[i];

    //it works
    Debug.Print($"{i}: isCashAvailable = {isCashAvailable[i]}, cashVal = {cashVal[i]}");
   }
```